# Exibir arquivo PDF salvo em um banco de dados MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um campo numa tabela onde coloco o arquivo PDF. O tipo deste campo é BLOB.

Queria saber como faço para exibir este arquivo numa página PHP, sem ter que criar diretório.

Quero só que o script acesse o campo dessa tabela, e me mostre o arquivo que está lá.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Só imprimir os dados após alterar o content-type da resposta:

```
<?php
header('content-type: application/pdf');
echo "..."; // Só imprimir os dados binários
?>
```

Opcionalmente, pode-se definir o nome (padrão) do arquivo:

```
<?php
header('content-type: application/pdf');
header('content-disposition: attachment; filename="arquivo.pdf"');
echo "..."; // Só imprimir os dados binários
?>
```

Comment: No seu primeiro exemplo pode-se acrescentar, por via das duvidas (nao sei se é o default) o `header('content-disposition: inline')`;

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar o método `fpassthru()` do PHP para passar os dados do seu BLOB diretamente para o PHP que o usuário está acessando.

http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fpassthru.php

Exemplo usando LOB (Large Object):

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('odbc:SAMPLE', 'db2inst1', 'ibmdb2');
$stmt = $db->prepare("select contenttype, imagedata from images where id=?");
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']));
$stmt->bindColumn(1, $type, PDO::PARAM_STR, 256);
$stmt->bindColumn(2, $lob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);

header("Content-Type: $type");
fpassthru($lob);
?>
```