# Apresentar conteúdo de campo "longblob" que contém ficheiro PDF

Tags: php, mysql, arquivo, blob

Tenho uma duvida em relação aos dados `longblob` que são guardados na Base de dados.

Eu atualmente tenho assim para os outros dados:

```
echo "<tr><td>Email:</td>";
echo "<td>";

if ($exibe['Email']) {
    echo $exibe['Email'];
} else {
    echo 'N/D';
}

echo "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Alvara Numero:</td>";
echo "<td>";

if ($exibe['AlvaraNumero']) {
    echo $exibe['AlvaraNumero'];
} else {
    echo 'N/D';
}

echo "</td>   </tr>";
```

E agora quero mostrar o anexo:

```
echo "<tr><td>Alvara Anexo:</td>";
echo "<td>";
```

Não sei qual é a melhor maneira se será mostrar ou fazer o Download para ver o ficheiro.

Comment: Acho que [essa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3298/como-fazer-para-exibir-aquivo-pdf-no-banco-da-dados-mysql) pergunta pode ajudar.

Answer (score 4):

O documento guardado na base de dados terá que ser recolhido num ficheiro de PHP isolado, de forma a que o mesmo contenha os cabeçalhos adequados à correcta interpretação dos dados.

Uma solução será aplicares uma ligação no código visualizado na tua pergunta, cuja mesma vai chamar o ficheiro responsável por apresentar o documento através de um parâmetro identificador da linha pretendida na tua tabela:

### Link para documento

Exemplo de criação de um link para um ficheiro PHP com um parâmetro a passar ao mesmo:

```
echo '
<tr>
  <td>
    Alvara Anexo:
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="caminho/ficheiro_mostra_pdf.php?id='.$exibe["id"].'" title="">
      Clique para ver documento PDF
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>';
```

<sup>**Notas:**

Estou a assumir que tens uma coluna `id` para identificar a linha na tabela que contém o documento.

Deverás actualizar/rectificar o nome da entrada na matriz `$exibe` para o nome da coluna que efectivamente existe na tua tabela.</sup>

### Ficheiro que apresenta documento

Em baixo o código do ficheiro com o nome `ficheiro_mostra_pdf.php` que vai recolher da base de dados os dados binários da linha que recebeu e fazer saída para o navegador com cabeçalho adequado para documento PDF:

> **NOTA:** Estou a usar [PHP mysql_*](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysql.php) porque tenho visto as tuas restantes perguntas a recorrem a este método para realização de consultas à base de dados, contudo, aconselho que optes por [outros métodos](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php) pois esta extensão do PHP está a ser removida.

```
<?php
// para debug, remover as 3 linhas quando em produção
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);


// verifica se existe identificador
if (isset($_GET["id"]) && ctype_digit($_GET["id"])) {

    // apanha identificador
    $id = $_GET["id"];

    /* define os acessos à base de dados
     */
    define("HOST", "localhost");     // Database Name
    define("DBUSER", "utilizador");  // Database user
    define("PASS", "password");      // Database password
    define("DB", "nome-base-dados"); // Database name

    // estabele ligação à base de dados
    $ligacao = mysql_connect(HOST, DBUSER, PASS) or die('Erro:' . mysql_error());

    // escolhe a base de dados
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB) or die(LANG_DB_CONNECT_FAIL);

    // consulta base de dados
    $resultado = mysql_query("SELECT meu_campo_blob FROM minha_tabela WHERE id='".$id."'");

    // verifica se recebeu algo
    if ($resultado) {

        // verifica se temos uma única linha
        if (mysql_num_rows($resultado)==1) {

            // recolhe os dados binários
            $registo = mysql_fetch_array($resultado);

            // verifica se contem dados
            if (is_array($registo) && isset($registo["meu_campo_blob"]) && $registo["meu_campo_blob"]!='') {

                $ficheiro = $registo["meu_campo_blob"];

                // cabeçalho identificador para o navegador
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
                header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
                header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                header('Content-Length: '.strlen($ficheiro));

                // faz saída para o navegador
                print $ficheiro;

            } else {
                echo "Sem conteúdo para gerar o PDF.";
            }

        } else {
            echo "O número de resultados não é 1.";
        }

    } else {
        echo "Não foi possível seleccionar o campo da base de dados";
    }

    // fecha a ligação à base de dados
    mysql_close($ligacao);

} else {
    echo "Não foi possível apurar o identificador do registo pretendido.";
}

?>
```

As verificações realizadas são básicas para garantir um mínimo de viabilidade na solução. Contudo, deverás garantir que o acesso a este ficheiro fica devidamente protegido contra acessos indevidos.

---

### Cabeçalhos

Alternativamente, podes adicionar mais cabeçalhos para melhor controlares a saída do teu documento, tais como a indicação de não fazer *cache*, o tipo de codificação da saída e o tamanho da mesma:

```
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($ficheiro));
```

Comment: +1 por causa dos cabeçalhos

Answer (score 2):

Dependendo do formato do arquivo você não pode exibi-lo diretamente na página, mas deverá colocar um link para o *download* do mesmo.

## Exibindo arquivos diretamente na página

Se o arquivo for do tipo texto (txt, xml, html, etc.) você pode exibi-lo diretamente na página. Use uma tag `<textarea>`, `<pre>` ou mesmo num `<div>` com o devido CSS.

Vejamos um exemplo:

```css
.conteudo-texto {
    display: block;
    unicode-bidi: embed;
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```php
echo "<tr><td>Alvara Anexo:</td>";
echo "<td><div class='conteudo-texto'>" . htmlentities($exibe['AlvaraConteudo']) . '</div></td>';
```

#### [Demo no Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7s3A2/1/)

Também é possível limitar o tamanho e colocar barra de rolagem, caso necessário, adicionando o CSS `overflow: scroll;`.

#### [Demo no Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7s3A2/2/)

O mesmo princípio pode ser aplicado se o anexo for uma imagem. Basta exibi-la no local com tamanhos máximos de largura e altura.

## Exibindo arquivos num `frame`, `iframe` ou *popup*

PDFs e alguns outros tipos de arquivos binários são reconhecidos por navegadores e plugins, mas devem ser exibidos numa página à parte.

### Nova página

Para exibir um PDF numa nova página, basta criar um link com o atributo `target` com valor `_blank`. O link deve apontar para uma página PHP que, por sua vez, irá exibir o conteúdo do arquivo.

Exemplo para um PDF:

```php
echo '<a href="visualizar_anexo.php?AlvaraNumero=' . $exibe['AlvaraNumero']) 
   . '" target="_blank">Abrir anexo</a>';
```

Então, o arquivo PHP teria algo como:

```php
<?php
if (isset($_GET['AlvaraNumero'])) {
    try {
        // recupera dados do alvará
        $conteudo_arquivo = ...
        $tamanho_arquivo = ...
        $nome_arquivo = ...

        header("Content-length: $tamanho_arquivo");
        header("Content-type: application/pdf");
        header("Content-disposition: inline; filename=$nome_arquivo");
        echo $conteudo_arquivo; 
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        // tratar erro
    }
}
```

### Popup

Para exibir numa popup, basta acrescentar um evento Javascript no link.

Exemplo:

```js
$('a').click(function() {
    w = 600;
    h = 600;
    x = 10;
    y = 10;
    window.open(this.href, 'anexo', "resizable=no, toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, menubar=no, status=no, directories=no, width=" + w + ", height=" + h + ", left=" + x + ", top=" + y);
    return false; //inibe o clique original para não abrir a nova janela
});
```

#### [Demo no Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mRsLG/)

Note que este é um exemplo simplificado. Você deve ajustar o seletor e os parâmetros conforme a sua necessidade.

### Frame

A terceira opção é exibir o arquivo num `frame` ou `iframe`. Exemplo:

```php
echo '<iframe src="visualizar_anexo.php?AlvaraNumero=' . $exibe['AlvaraNumero']) 
   . '"></iframe>';
```

Adicione um estilo CSS ao `iframe` para deixá-lo num tamanho adequado.

## Forçando o download do arquivo

Caso queira simplesmente forçar o download do arquivo, basta adicionar um link, de forma semelhante à forma de exibir em outra página.

Exemplo:

```php
echo '<a href="download_anexo.php?AlvaraNumero=' . $exibe['AlvaraNumero']) 
   . '">Abrir anexo</a>';
```

O script PHP de download será semelhante ao arquivo para exibição, alterando apenas o *header* `Content-disposion`.

Exemplo:

```php
<?php
if (isset($_GET['AlvaraNumero'])) {
    try {
        // recupera dados do alvará
        $conteudo_arquivo = ...
        $tamanho_arquivo = ...
        $nome_arquivo = ...

        header("Content-length: $tamanho_arquivo");
        header("Content-type: application/pdf");
        header("Content-disposition: download; filename=$nome_arquivo");
        echo $conteudo_arquivo; 
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        // tratar erro
    }
}
```

## Recuperando o *mime type* automaticamente

O *Mime Type* é uma constante padronizada que diz ao navegador qual o tipo de conteúdo sendo enviado pelo PHP. Nos exemplos, usei o valor `application/pdf` fixo no código.

No entanto, você pode usar a função [finfo_file](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.finfo-file.php) para recuperar esse valor automaticamente, se o arquivo estiver gravado em algum diretório. Mas provavelmente você não vai querer isso, então pode usar a função [`finfo_buffer`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.finfo-buffer.php) para obter o tipo do arquivo através do conteúdo.

Exemplo:

```php
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime =  $finfo->buffer($conteudo_arquivo);
```