# Download de planilha usando a classe PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Eu achei essa classe phpexcel, consigo gerar arquivos xls buscando dados do MySQL.
Funciona muito bem.
Mas preciso pegar uma planilha que estar armazenada como modelo no banco e apenas alguns campos em branco.

Quero pegar essa planilha, carregar, preencher as células e depois baixar ela.

Comment: Tem algum código? aconteceu algum problema?

Comment: Estava começando do zero, mas consegui andar um pouco tirando algumas macros que existiam na planilha.
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(15);

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
   ->setCellValue('C3', $numRegistro);

Comment: Para fazer o download pode usar esse código 
`header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=plan.xls');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
 
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');`

Comment: Obrigado! Vou testar aqui.

Comment: Aproveitando o espaço, funcionou perfeitmente.
Agora eu queria pegar um arquivo em armazenei em um campo blob no mysql, eu gostaria de pegar ele, armazenar temporariamente, editar e baixar ele na máquina, tem como fazer?

Comment: Acredito que essa [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3298/91) pode ajudar.

Comment: Valeu, vou da uma olhada na documentação dessa classe aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Para força o download de um planilha do excel é necessário definir o cabeçalho, informando como o conteudo deve ser tratado pelo navegador e invocar o método `save()` de algum [writer](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer)

```
//definição do cabeçalho
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=plan.xls');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

//cria uma planilha no formato do excel 2003
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

As versões mais recentes, documentações, tutoriais etc podem ser encontradas em: [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

Comment: Obrigado pela colaboração.

Answer (score 1):

**Para gerar XLSX use**

Defina em **$xlsName** o nome do XLSX com a extensão. **Example: $xlsName = 'teste.xlsx';**

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$xlsName.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

**Para XLS use**

Defina em **$xlsName** o nome do XLS com a extensão. **Example: $xlsName = 'teste.xls';**

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$xlsName.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: O código não está mais no codeplex, está no [github](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

Comment: Versão anterior ao PHP 5.3.3 recomendo gerar XLS, pois algumas das classes do XLXS possui funções não existentes em PHP anteriores à 5.4.0. A versão recomendada do PHP parar gerar XLSX é 5.4.0